# Matlab logncdf function is not producing expected result

Tags: matlab

So on this problem it seems pretty straight forward we are given

mean of x = 10,281 and sigma of x = 4112.4

We are asked to determine P(X<15,000)

Now I thought the code for this in matlab should be super straightforward

```
mu = 10281
sigma = 4112.4
p = logncdf(15000,10281,4112.4)
```

However this gives

p = .0063

The given answer is .8790 and just looking at p  you can tell it is wrong because we are at 15000 which is over the mean which means it should be above .5.  What is the deal with this function?

I saw somewhere you might need to take the exp(15000) for x in the function that results in a probability of 1 which is too high.

Any pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that the distribution you're dealing with is `Lognormal`?

Comment: Agree with @Sardar_Usama. normcdf(15000,10281,4112.4) gives 0.8744 so the given answer you assumed is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
%If X is lognormally distributed with parameters:-
mu = 10281;
sigma = 4112.4;

%then log(X) is normally distributed with following parameters:
mew_actual = log((mu^2)/sqrt(sigma^2+mu^2));
sigma_actual = sqrt(log((sigma^2)/(mu^2) +1));
```

Now you can use either of the following to compute CDF:-

```
p = cdf('Normal',log(15000),mew_actual,sigma_actual)
```

or

```
p=logncdf(15000,mew_actual,sigma_actual)
```

which gives `0.8796`
(which I believe is the correct answer)

The answer given to you is `0.8790` because if you solve the question by hand, you'll get something like: `z = 1.172759` and when you look this value in the table, you can only find `z = 1.17`(without the rest of decimal places) and for which `φ(z)=0.8790`.

You can verify the exact answer using [this calculator](http://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=55). The related screenshot is attached below:

[image: exactvalue]

Comment: Your answer is numerically correct; however, the explanation is wrong (or at least scant). In the original question, `mu` and `sigma` (@AKNorth) are the mean and standard deviation of the random variable in question (`X`). However, in Matlab's `logncdf` function `mu` and `sigma` are the mean and standard deviation of the related normally distributed random variable (`Y = log(X)`). All you need is the connection between these parameters, which is correctly given by you.